# Trying to create a calculation script of a json array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a calculation script from a JSON array (can be more or less entries) where the amount of weeks and seasons have points, and all together it should output a total, but not larger than 50.
Somewhere i make a mistake as my result is 0. As i am quite new to PHP this script already took me some time :-) Eager to learn.. can someone point me what i am doing wrong?

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [experiences] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [unit] => seasons
                    [description] => skischool 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 5
                    [unit] => weeks
                    [description] => skischool 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [unit] => seasons
                    [description] => skischool 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [unit] => weeks
                    [description] => skischool 4
                )

        )

)
```

And here is my idea of the script:

```
$incoming = json_decode($text, true);
$experiences = Sanitize::getVar($incoming, 'experiences');
$total = 0;
$weeks_points = 0.5;
$seasons = 5;
if(!empty($experiences['experiences'])) {
    foreach($experiences['experiences'] as $experience) {

        if($experience['unit'] == 'seasons') {
            $total = $total + ($experience['quantity'] * $sessons);
        } else if($experience['unit'] == 'weeks') {
            $total = $total + ($experience['quantity'] * $weeks_points);
        }
    }
}
$total = round($total);
echo $total = $total > 50 ? 50 : $total;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but shouldn't the if and the loop look like this?

```
if(!empty($experiences)) {
    foreach($experiences as $experience) {
```